# LibGDX render and update calling speed

Tags: java, libgdx, render

In the ApplicationAdapter class, I override the `render()` method and draws my game from there.
I also have an own method: `update()` inside the render method which is where I want to update everything.

The render() method is as I know called ~60 times a second.
I dont want my update method to be dependent on how many times the render method is called. 
***I want the render method to render as much as the device can handle below 60 FPS.***
***I also want the update method to get called at a fixed rate: 60 times a second.***

---

I´ve tried to call my update method 60 times a second in my render method like this:

```
double beforeMillis;
double FPS=4; //test
double millisPassed=0;
int x=0;


@Override 
public void render () {
    beforeMillis=System.currentTimeMillis();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(tex, x, 10);
    batch.end();
    millisPassed+=(System.currentTimeMillis()-beforeMillis);
    if(millisPassed>=1000/FPS){
        update();
        millisPassed=0;
    }
}
```

...but it updates like once every four seconds.

---

**Any good way of doing this? Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you posted won't compare accurate time, because it ignores all the time spent doing things between `batch.end()` and the next call to `render()`, some of which occurs in the libgdx backend. And if you update after drawing in the `render` method, you will always have at least one visual frame of lag.

A basic implementation of a fixed timestep update in libgdx would be like this:

```
static final double DT = 1/60.0;
static final int MAX_UPDATES_PER_FRAME = 3; //for preventing spiral of death
private long currentTimeMillis;

public void create() {
    currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

public void render() {
    long newTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    float frameTimeSeconds = (newTimeMillis - currentTimeMillis) / 1000f;
    currentTimeMillis = newTimeMillis;

    int updateCount = 0;
    while (frameTimeSeconds > 0f && updateCount <= MAX_UPDATES_PER_FRAME) {
        float deltaTimeSeconds = Math.min(frameTimeSeconds, DT);
        update(deltaTimeSeconds);
        frameTimeSeconds -= deltaTimeSeconds;
        ++updateCount;
    }

    draw();
}
```

This does result in `update` occurring more than 60 times a second, because it gets updated with the "leftovers" to keep the visuals current (no stuttering). The `update(float delta)` method must be designed to use a variable delta time.

You can do a truly fixed update as described [here](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/) in the last two sections, but that has the disadvantage of visual stuttering or needing to implement a one-frame delay and interpolating ahead.